# Class design problem - passing a class type?

Tags: c#, xml, oop

I have the following code in a method of a class:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FooClass));
```

How do I pass into the constructor or a parameter of the class - the foo class?

I think it has something to do with reflection as you can't pass as a parameter just a class name - so the following code makes some sort of sense (thanks to Aidan) -

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(Type.GetType("namespace.FooClass"));
```

Comment: Question needs to be a little more clear...not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Please show what "foo" is. Is it a class, or a variable. The names of classes normally start with upper case in .NET, so would have expected "Foo" if you meant it to be a class.

Comment: Can you please construct a full example of the problem you're having and post it. And include namespaces and everything, including complete exceptions. We've been guessing wrong for an hour now.

Comment: And BTW, this is .NET, not Java. There are types, which are represented by instances of the class System.Type. Some types are classes. There's no such thing as a "class type".

Comment: You need to be more clear about what it is your asking about. Your question does not make much sense, and people are having a hard time figuring out how to respond to the question as you currently have it stated. Please clarify your question so that you can get a useful answer.

Comment: I didn't bother putting the whole class in - because I didn't want all that extra stuff to detract from my main problem - I would have thought "I have the following code in a method of a class" - would indicate some kind of context.  Sorry to those who didn't understand my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
void serializeme(Object o) {
   Type t = o.GetType();
   XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(t);
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want this:

```
class YourClass {
   Type type;

   public YourClass(Type type) {
       this.type = type;
   }

   public XmlSerializer Method() {
       return new XmlSerializer(type);
   }
}

...

new YourClass(typeof(Foo));
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(foo.GetType());
```

Comment: What do you mean it needs to examine the class type?  Assuming foo is an instance of the object you want to serialize which is publicly visible, the XmlSerializer will use reflection to "examine" the class.

Comment: Sorry I'm being a bit crap about what I am trying to ask - I'm not really sure how to phrase it as I still trying to get my head round the problem

Comment: No problem, I'm just trying to understand as well.  Please edit your original question with any additional details you can add to help clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Add a type parameter to the method:

```
 public XmlSerializer Method<T>()
 {
    return new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
 }
```

you would then call the method as `Method<Foo>();`

Comment: I presume you mean new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).

Answer (score 0):

Consider this snippet of code:

```
Type t = foo.GetType();
XmlSerializer fooSerializer = MakeSerializer(t);
```

...

```
private XmlSerializer MakeSerializer(Type myType)
{
  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(myType);
  return serializer;
}
```

Comment: What's the added value of the MakeSerializer method ? why not use the XmlSerializer constructor directly ?

Answer (score 0):

You would use reflection to achieve what (I believe) you want to do.

You would use the XmlSerializer(Type) override of the XmlSerializer constructor.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(Type.GetType("namespace.Foo"));
```

or

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(fooInstance.GetType());
```

depending if you have an instance of the type on hand.

Comment: I am getting an exception thrown (Type.GetType("namespace.Foo")) - 
"Could not load type 'fooNamespace.Bar' from assembly 'FooBar, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' - any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you have to use a parameterless constructor with the XmlSerializer.  So the only constructor of foo that XmlSerializer will use is this:

```
public foo()
{
}
```

Comment: that's *almost* correct... you can actually have an `internal` constructor, if you generate the serialization assembly with sgen.exe, and declare that assembly as friend with `InternalsVisibleToAttribute`